# How to make variables configurable for an Angular application in IBM Bluemix?

Tags: node.js, angular5, ibm-cloud, config, environment

I am having an application in which the server side code is in Node.js and the client code is in Angular 5. This application is together built and run using webpack. I have deployed this application to IBM Cloud. However, I need to keep certain parameters used by the client code configurable. Currently these parameters are stored in a config.ts file. Hence, each time we need to change a value, we need to build the application and push on Bluemix again.

For server, this can be done through environment variables. But process.env is not accessible on the client side.

I want to enable changing these parameters without the need to build or push the application on Bluemix again. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You most probably need a simple API call to deliver your configuration in one form or the other from server side to client.

For process.env -variables you still need serverside restart in order to take effect of the values. If you want to be more agile, you need to have those e.g. in database and read them on each API call.